# Torah literature on Challenges

Tags: sources-mekorot, test

Is there any source in Torah literature that says when a challenge becomes more difficult it's a sign that it's almost finished?

Comment: Could you please [edit] this post to indicate why you think that there may be such a concept in Torah literature?

Comment: chevlei moshiach?

Answer (score 1):

This idea can be seen, for example, in the [Yalkut Shimoni on Psalms 22](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.685.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), describing the salvation from Haman:

> ד"א למנצח למי שהוא קופץ כאיל ומאיר לעולם בשעת חשכה, ואימתי הוא מאיר בלילה אע"פ שהוא לילה יש בו אורה הלבנה והכוכבים והמזלות, אימתי הוא חשך בעלות השחר והלבנה שוקעת והכוכבים נכנסין והמזלות הולכים להם אותה שעה אין חשך גדול הימנו, ואותה שעה הקב"ה מעלה את השחר מתוך החשך ומאיר לעולם, והן הוא אומר והנה אימה חשכה גדולה נופלת עליו, חשכה זה מדי בימי אסתר.

Accordingly, the Maharal explains [in his second introduction to Ohr Chadash](https://www.sefaria.org/Ohr_Chadash%2C_Second_Introduction_to_Ohr_Chadash.4?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) that the redemption commemorated by Purim occurred just after the darkest moment of that exile, just as dawn follows the darkest part of night:

> ולכך נקרא גאולת אסתר שחר כי הלילה הוא חשך וקודם עלות השחר הוא חושך נוסף על חשך הלילה וכן היה בימי מרדכי ואסתר שהיה חשך תוך חשך כמו שאמר הכתוב (דברים לא, יח) ואנכי הסתר אסתיר כי היו תוך הגלות שהיו תחת יד אחשורוש ועתה נוסף על זה חשך וצרות המן וזה לגמרי דומה אל קודם עלות השחר שהוא חושך על חשך והאדם משתוקק אל האור והיו הם מתענים וצועקים אל הש"י שתבא להם אור התשועה.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Torah-based challenges of "Endurance" (סֵּ֣בֶל) having a breaking point : We read in [Iyov (Job) 2:6] that Satan is allowed to emotionally & physically "challenge" Iyov * to the point of "preserving His life" (נַפְשׁ֖וֹ שְׁמֹֽר). - Preserving a Living (faithful) Soul during emotional / physical pain is the challenge also faced by King David in [Tehillim (Psalms) 22]. Every living soul found on earth becomes the reward of our Redeemer (גֹּ֣אֲל) as we successfully complete Satan's challenge to sustain faith in Him. [Iyov (Job) 19:25] - The rules related to a living soul were provided to Moshe in the Torah [Shemot (Exodus) 20]. The Author of the Torah offers us help in knowing where others have failed Satan's challenge to ensure we endure and find His way back home.

Comment: Thank you for your post. To be honest, I have difficulty following your train of thought. How does this answer the question?

Comment: Our Redeemer presents us signs in the heavens and on earth of that He is our Creator. It is our responsibility to testify that He is in control of the universe and we are not, even in the moment of ultimate suffering brought as a test from His messenger Satan. * If our faith in our Redeemer does not die during temptations, He restores our life abundantly. [Iyov (Job) 42:10-17]